# SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name for mvc3 SaveChanges() after schema change

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, schema

I've built an MVC3 application using the Entity Framework database first approach. I was able to round trip all objects, then needed to make a schema change. After changing the database schema and updating the .edmx, SaveChanges() fails for objects that map to a db table with column changes.

Specifically:  Originally I had a table 'project_issue_installation' that had column 'installation_system_id'. I've changed the schema to remove the 'installation_system_id' from 'project_issue_installation', ran an 'update model from database', recompiled and checked the datmodel .edmx.  No errors on compilation and the model .edmx looks correct.

When I try to persist a project_issue_installation object, I get a Invalid column name 'installation_system_id' exception.

I've searched the entire solution for 'installation_system_id' and came up with nothing.  Can anyone point me to where the app is holding on to that column name?

-Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem in the db schema, not the EF model.  My DBA missed a trigger that was still pointing to the old column.